# c# avoid zip folder issue

Tags: c#

I need to zip a file in the folder c:\projects\test\test.log
I need to zip the test.log to a zip folder.I am using Ionic.zip.dll.
when I zipped the folder, it is entirely adding the folder c:\projects\test\test.log.
I need to add the test.log to a zip folder

for eg.jan.zip. it should contain only one file. no folder structure needed.

Thanks

Comment: `c:\projects\test\test.log` is not the path to a folder. That's a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
zipFile.AddFile(filename);
```

you should use

```
zipFile.AddFile(filename, "");
```

That will insert the file at the root of the zip file, ie without a path.